# SO Tag synonym request: floyd-warshall --> floyd-algorithm

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

The tags [floyd-warshall](/questions/tagged/floyd-warshall) and [floyds-algorithm](/questions/tagged/floyds-algorithm) are currently 2 separate tags, which are being used for the same thing. Would someone please create tag synonym for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some times back, someone changed the tag wiki for [floyd-algorithm](/questions/tagged/floyd-algorithm) to use for Floyd's cycle finding algorithm. However, the tag is still confusing, and some people tag both [floyd-algorithm](/questions/tagged/floyd-algorithm) and [floyd-warshall](/questions/tagged/floyd-warshall) in their question, or use [floyd-algorithm](/questions/tagged/floyd-algorithm) for Floyd-Warshall algorithm.

I have:

- Retagged all incorrectly tagged questions.
- Retagged the rest of [floyd-algorithm](/questions/tagged/floyd-algorithm) (which are questions about Floyd's cycle finding algorithm) to [floyd-cycle-finding](/questions/tagged/floyd-cycle-finding) where appropriate
- Edited some of the questions into shape along the way.